# Jenkins job list changes when running as a service and from CLI

Tags: java, jenkins, hudson

I was running jenkins as a service on my windows machine, and I had setup a few jobs. Now, when I shutdown the service and ran the same jenkins from command line, using **"java -jar jenkins.war"**, all jobs are gone. Now, I thought it would delete configuration, and i started it back as service. Now, all the jobs were back again. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by setting JENKINS_HOME to the jenkins folder, and the launching java -jar jenkins.war